# android studio screen size not same on emulator

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

Helloo im making a project on android studio.my workbench screen size is not same working on emulator

[in my phone when i trying](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2898-202.html)

[in android studio when i developing](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2898-203.html)

i got a scroolview vertical ann it got a linear layout in scrollwiew.i want to make same to every phone.

my menu.xml

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="chosse one!"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@mipmap/love"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@mipmap/krm"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@mipmap/rak"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@mipmap/rght"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/left"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because devices have different densities and screen sizes. Device that you test your app on has lower density screen and/or smaller screen height, so it's compressing the layout.
You can design the same layout several times to work with multiple densities like hdpi, xhdpi, mdpi etc. more information can be found there: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html